# How to edit an original text file and break the lines that reaches a maximum length. Java

Tags: java, file, buffer

I have a text file that I want to organize by setting a maximum length for each line to break and creates a new line afterwards. I know that I can open, read, and write on a file, but could I fix the same file without having to create a new file?

I tried writing different codes to do so, but I still have a little experience with IO API and I always confront a problem. This what I came up with so far without having any problems:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        File file = new File("data/test.txt");
        BufferedReader br = null;
        BufferedWriter bw = null;

        try {
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
            final int MAX_LENGTH = 80;
            String line;

            while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                if(line.length() > MAX_LENGTH) {
                    //I want to break the line if it reached the MAX_LENGTH
                    //without overwriting data or skipping them
                }
            }
            br.close();
            bw.close();
        } catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I would also appreciate any suggestions or ideas regarding my code.

Comment: Write the new content to a temp file, when you're done, delete the original and rename the temp file into it's place

Comment: @MadProgrammer I know, but isn't it possible to just write on the same file without having to create a new one?

Comment: No, not really.  If you wanted to, you'd have to continuously read forward, moving the contents of the file "down" out the range of the changes you want to make...easier to use a temp file

Comment: @MadProgrammer That's true, but I will be doing almost the same thing when I use a temp file. I would still have to read forwardly until the line of that sentence becomes legal, don't you think?

Comment: Not really, you read the line from the original file, add how many ever lines you want to the new file and repeat.  It would be faster

Comment: @MadProgrammer what is the best method that does that to a large line?

Comment: Assuming your don't want to read the contents of the file into memory, IMHO, two files is your best bet

Comment: I think you misunderstood my last question, however, if you would explain your idea in a source code that show how your methodology fits into my code it would be much appreciated and well understood @MadProgrammer

Answer (score 0):

Writing to a file is destructive process, even if open the file in seekable mode, writing to a position of the file will simply overwrite what's there.  Personally, I'd use a second file to write the changes to and then delete the original file and rename the temp file back in it's place

```
File original = new File("data/test.txt");
File tmp = new File("data/temp.txt");

try {
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(original))) {
        try (BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(tmp))) {

            String text = null;
            while ((text = br.readLine()) != null) {

                // For each line we read, we need to break the line
                // down to the MAX_LENGTH and write
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(text);
                while (sb.length() > MAX_LENGTH) {
                    String line = sb.substring(0, MAX_LENGTH);
                    sb.delete(0, MAX_LENGTH);
                    bw.write(line);
                    bw.newLine();
                }
                // In case we removed all the text during the previous loop
                if (sb.length() > 0) {
                    bw.write(sb.toString());
                    bw.newLine();
                }

            }

        }
    }

    if (original.delete()) {
        tmp.renameTo(original);
    } else {
        throw new IOException("Failed to remove " + original);
    }
} catch (IOException exp) {
    exp.printStackTrace();
}
```

As an idea